# Electronic hobbyist project-short circuit detector

Tags: transistors, breadboard, short-circuit

I am doing this circuit which I took from from the internet for my project. I have 3 questions:
The circuit show glow 2 leds one if there is a short circuit if there is one in J1 and the other if there is no short circuit.
Consider the transistors as general purpose NPN and PNP transistors.
1. Will this circuit work?
2. If so,what is the logic behind the working of the circuit.
3. Does anyone have an idea of how the resistance values are calculated.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You need to quickly replace this camera picture of your computer screen with an actual image file or screenshot - no one is going to look at this.  You are also going to have to explain the purpose and where whatever you are testing is supposed to connect.

Comment: ... and please turn of the background grid to improve legibility, if possible. Add in a link to the web page.

Comment: Define "work". Tell us what you expect the circuit to do based on your knowledge of the circuit.

Comment: The fact that the schematic is specifying part numbers for TO-39 (metal can) transistors is a bad sign. Those have been effectively obsolete for ages…

Comment: If there is a short circuit where? On J1? Please edit your question to explain. Why did you not add a link to the web page?

Comment: I took this from an YouTube video https://youtu.be/JhHvSr6Qjv8

Answer (score 1):

Assume the switch is open on power-up.

- On power-up Q1 and Q2 will be off.
- A current will flow through R1 - U1 - R2 - U2 lighting both LEDs dimly. The voltage at the bottom of U1 will be about 2.5 V.
- Q2 will now have voltage on the base so it will turn on.
- Q2 turning on will turn on Q1. This will short out U1 turning the top LED off and giving full voltage to R2 - U2 making this go bright.
- If the switch is closed (short-circuited) the top LED will go full brightness and there will be no voltage across the lower LED so it will turn off.

Note that when the switch is closed there will be a momentary short-circuit on Q1 while Q2 turns off. This is not a very good design.

> 1. Will this circuit work?

Yes, although Q1 is under a bit of stress sometimes.

> 2. If so,what is the logic behind the working of the circuit.

Explained above.

> 3. Does anyone have an idea of how the resistance values are calculated.

- For the LEDs you choose a value that limits the current to a safe value. Since you need about 2 V for the LED you need to drop 3 V across the series resistor so you have \$ V \$. Next choose the current you want through the LED and you have \$ I \$. Then use Ohm's Law to find R. \$ R = \frac {V}{I} \$.
- R3 and R6 aren't needed as there is a lower resistance path to ground through the lower LED.
- R4 and R5 are chosen to supply enough base current to turn the transistors hard-on.

Comment: But it will work right?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: What is power up mean

Comment: It means switching on or connecting the battery (which provides the power). The voltage will then rise.